# Peformance impact of the presence of an unused TEXT field

Tags: mysql, performance

Does the presence of having a large `TEXT` field cause performance issues even if that field is not being used but other fields are?

The engine I am using is InnoDB, the `TEXT` field averages around 10KB and I will have around 1 million rows.

For those interested, the TEXT field simply contains JSON data that I return from an API that charges me per request. So I am keeping the data incase I need to parse more data from it.

Comment: This is a big vague.  Performance when Inputs, Updates, Deletes< Reads? datbase overhead or user perception? where?  If you're never selecting the field performance should be fine.  when you go to select the field there will be a big longer retrieval due to the overhead of the 10kb and read.  Initial writes will also take longer again 10kb.  but as to reads of other data it will be slightly slower due to how the data is written to disk and spacing but if you're using indexes, it should be negligible.

Comment: The field will not be used at all in production. I was wondering if it will have impact on other queries that do not make use of this field, but I am guessing you are saying no impact? I am asking about performance of inputs, deletes, updates etc of other fields but not the TEXT field.

Comment: The initial insert of data will cause a slight delay as the I/O will be greater.  Reads will take a fraction of a second longer depending on how the data is written to storage due to the read heads having to seek longer to pickup all the record data.  Both of these minor increases should have relatively low impact on general read/update/delete statements to the "OTHER" data; but it will have a SMALL impact.  so if you have a high performance system needing to process hundreds of thousands of transactions.  This might not be good enough.  but if you have a few hundred users, should be fine.